# Not getting a keydown interrupt

Tags: jquery

Does someone see in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stevea/36Tfx/1/)

Why I'm not getting a keydown interrupt? I get a click interrupt in  the orange box but no interrupt if I click in the beige box and then hit a key.

Thanks

```
$(function () {
    $('#beigeBox').keydown(function(e) {                        
            console.log("In keydown handler");
            if(e.keyCode == 68) {  // 'D'
                console.log("Got 68");
            }
    });

    $('#orangeBox').click(function() {                      
            console.log("orangeBox clicked");
    });

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `beigeBox` div is not `contenteditable`, therefore no `keydown` events can be registered on it. Your `#orangeBox` `div` on the other hand contains a `click` handler, which does register (since `div` is clickable).

Here's a demo where your `beigeBox` will register a `keydown`, since `contenteditable` is enabled: http://jsfiddle.net/tymeJV/36Tfx/3/

Comment: Hmmm.  Ok, good point!  In the real application, though, I have a checkbox that you can click to duplicate a div. What I'm trying to do here is create a Ctrl-D shortcut for it. But the div to be duplicated is not necessarily contenteditable and I don't want to force the user to click in  certain place before Ctrl-D works. So is there a way to sense Ctrl-D no matter where the mouse is? (This might be morphing into a new question.)

Comment: @Steve -- You can do `$(document).on('keydown', function(e) { //check the e.which for key });` to catch the keypresses. You'll have to lookup the keycodes tho. Might be a bad idea running a function everytime the user presses a key tho.

Comment: Thanks! That works.  Well, not quite.  There's still a problem with other applications get the Ctrl-D first, but I put that question in a new StackOverflow at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18522385/how-to-get-first-pick-at-keydown.

Answer (score 0):

Try this [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/36Tfx/29/)

Code:

```
$(function () {

    $('#beigeBox').keypress(function(event) {

        alert("In keydown handler");       

        if (event.which == 68) {

            event.preventDefault();
            alert("Got 68");
        }                   
    });

    $('#orangeBox').click(function() {

        alert("orangeBox clicked");

    });
```