# How to get first pick at keydown (preventing "add bookmark" dialog from showing)

Tags: javascript, jquery, bookmarks

I have a checkbox in my jQuery application that you can check to duplicate a `<div>`. I'd like now to create a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> shortcut for the operation. I can sense <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> with:

```
$(document).on('keydown',function(e) {  
    debugger;
    if((e.keyCode == 68) && e.ctrlKey){
        $('.duplicate').trigger('click');
    }
});
```

But it looks like Firefox is capturing the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> first and putting up a dialog to *"Edit a bookmark."*

How can I get the interrupt first, and then I'll kill it when I'm done? I don't want my users to have to dismiss a Firefox dialog every time they enter <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `e.preventDefault();`:

```
$(document).on('keydown',function(e) {  
    //debugger;
    if((e.keyCode == 68) && e.ctrlKey){
        $('.duplicate').trigger('click');
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

See **[demo page here](http://jsbin.com/EdIKaNU/2)** (edit the demo [here](http://jsbin.com/EdIKaNU/2/edit)).

On a side note, it is **not a good usability practice** to override widely-known keys/commands. While you can achieve that, it is advisable and better to use another combination of keys.

Comment: Regarding default actions, I know the default for a submit button is to submit the form and the default for a link is to go to the URL.  But how did "opening a bookmark editing dialog" become the default action for Ctrl-D in Firerfox?  Is this just something that Firefox wired up internally in the browser, because it's their browser and it's their dialog and they can do whatever they want in their browser?

Comment: The side note about usability is that CTRL-D in browsers are usually reserved to bookmarking. That's not a Firefox specific shortcut. You can try it, in all major browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari, IE)  CTRL-D does the same: add a bookmark. On the other hand, though, overwriting it can be not such a bad thing, if, as you said, CTRL-D is what people are used to from desktop drawing applications. You see, this is not about what CTRL-D should be used for or not, it's really about what is more intuitive for users. If your user base is used to CTRL-D for that, then it is OK to overwrite it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `e.preventDefault();`?

Or a better alternative - pick a different combination. Users typically don't like it when you start messing with their key bindings. On many sites (trello and github come to mind), there are no control keys at all. You can invoke special functionality just by typing a single character (on github "t" opens a page where you can type a filename and it will filter files in your repository). And in most cases that should be fine. You don't typically need to be able to type things on the html `body`. You would just want to make sure they're not inside an input or textarea before you fire the functionality.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Duplicating a box or image, though, just "has" to be Ctrl-D because it's unforgetable and it's what people are used to from desktop drawing applications. So for better or worse I'm gong to go forward with Ctrl-D.  The e.preventDefault() shut down the Firefox popup so that's out of my hair.

Comment: Make sure you try it in other browsers too. In theory, they'll all work the same. In practice, however, they often have differences (most notably IE).